# Simulating *server-like* port activity (software ports only) for academic purpose on a Linux system

Tags: c++, linux, port, simulation

I am working on an algorithm that *monitors* the behavior of software ports and accordingly sends notifications to the user about suspicious activity through email.

This projects moves forward in 3 parts:

**1.** Creating or rather what I am calling *simulating* a lot of activity on my computers ports.

**2.** Monitoring this port activity and using my algorithm to determine suspicious activity.

**3.** Sending email to the users with my conclusions.

From this, I am having problem with **simulating** *lots and lots of activity on a number of software ports on my system*. Basically I need **raw data** to work with. I mean my algorithm is going to need a large amount of port activity in the first place! now i do not have a *production server* for myself! So how do i (sort of) replicate or simulate the port activity of *large scale* servers on my puny desktop ? Of course; I actually don't need to actually *run* hundreds of websites, just need enough software port activity to get my algorithm enough data to work with .. any ideas people?

Comment: What kind of ports? Any hardware ports? Network protocol ports?

Comment: software ports. just software ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your needs perfectly. "Simulating" can be thought of in two ways. Nevertheless, here is the answer.

What is the design of your application? If it is "straightforward" (or "naive"), that is, you check the *actual* ports on the machine and do the action afterwards, than the problem of simulating it lies in this design.

---

(The rest is based on this assumption)

You should have your design much more modularized, removing coupling and separating concerns.
There are basically three concerns in your application: monitoring *physical* ports, making decision based on the activity of *logical* ports (here, the separation) and finally, notification behaviour (sending emails / whatever).

Each of these parts should be self-contained. Testable as-is, without need for the other parts of the application.

Result of this design: trivial simulation. For the "simulation" part, you only need to simulate the second concern, not the first.

Possible solution: in the company I worked some time ago, they were making low-level network heavy application. They used blackboard very successfully. They filled the blackboard with network-related events, and the code reacted to these events possibly generating new ones which were then taken back to the hardware. This elegantly let them to test application in various scenarios of networking action (like inserting/removing network card etc.) without actually painfully trying to *actually* simulate it.

---

If your question was trying to *really* simulate *physical* activity on ports, someone can probably suggest some white hat "simulating attack" products/services. You would need second computer probably to issue the network activity from outside (because you probably discriminate localhost activity from outside network activity).

Comment: Sorry the question was not clear to you; So after reading your answer I can say that only the third part is useful to me. So from what i understand, you are suggesting that I must use another computer to send data on my computers ports ? could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: I have extensively modified the question now, i think this will help you understand my problem better.

Comment: It is still not clear enough; I mean, it still seems to me that having design I suggested and feeding lots of simulated traffic in the second layer is enough and you do not need the real physical first layer. As I understand your question now, you are concerned with application that does some decisions based on shape of the traffic... no need for that traffic to be real, simulated is good enough.

Comment: BTW, you can go by without two computers easily - use virtualized system. You can issue lot of traffic into virtual machine from the host machine, just write a program that does it. If you use the design I suggested in the answer, you can simply "capture" the characteristics of the traffic and then "replay" it only to the secind layer, without actually issuing that traffic physically again and again.